# Combining DefineVerbatimEnvironment with UseVerbatim

Tags: fancyvrb

I would like to combine the power of `\DefineVerbatimEnvironment` with `\UseVerbatim` within a combined beamer presentation and handout scenario. I have already defined the environment `coding`, and now I can typeset my code using

```
\begin{coding}
  foo->bar( ).
\end{coding}
```

I can also define and re-use verbatim snippets in their stand-alone version:

```
\begin{SaveVerbatim}{Foo}
  foo->bar( ).
\end{SaveVerbatim}

\UseVerbatim{Foo}
```

The problem is that the latter is typeset using the default `fancyvrb` options. How can I combine the two so that the saved text is displayed using my custom environment?

---

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}

\DefineVerbatimEnvironment{coding}{Verbatim}{numbers=left,fontsize=\small}

\begin{document}

\begin{coding}
  foo->bar( ).
\end{coding}

Yup. This works.

\begin{SaveVerbatim}{Foo}
  foo->bar( ).
  boo->baz( ).
  cat->code( ).
\end{SaveVerbatim}

\UseVerbatim{Foo}
\UseVerbatim{Foo}
\UseVerbatim{Foo}

Yup, this works as well -- but it uses the default format, not my custom environment: larger font, no line numbers.

\end{document}
```

Comment: It would be best if you posted a complete [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228).  In lieu of that you can pass the same options to `SaveVerbatim` as you used to create the `coding` environment.

Comment: @AndrewSwann: I've added the MNWE. Passing the options to `SaveVerbatim` won't work in my case, because I need slightly different environment definitions for the slides and the handouts (different font sizes).

Comment: The fontsize can be passed to the `\UseVerbatim` command as an optional argument, e.g. `\UseVerbatim[fontsize=\small]{Foo}`.  However, line numbering doesn't seem to work in this set-up.

Answer (score 3):

Taking a look inside `fancyvrb`, there is a mechanism to extend existing or create new verbatim commands in quite a general way. The key is `\FV@Command`, which takes a keyval list of settings and an 'internal' command to execute. You'll find that `\UseVerbatim` is defined as

```
\def\UseVerbatim{\FV@Command{}{UseVerbatim}}
```

This suggests a couple of fixes. First, you could simply redefine `\UseVerbatim` to use your settings:

```
\def\UseVerbatim{\FV@Command{numbers=left,fontsize=\small}{UseVerbatim}}
```

Alternatively, you could create a related command, say `\UseCoding`, and leave `\UseVerabtim` alone:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}

\DefineVerbatimEnvironment{coding}{Verbatim}{numbers=left,fontsize=\small}
\makeatletter
\def\UseCoding{\FV@Command{numbers=left,fontsize=\small}{UseVerbatim}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}

\begin{coding}
  foo->bar( ).
\end{coding}

Yup. This works.

\begin{SaveVerbatim}{Foo}
  foo->bar( ).
  boo->baz( ).
  cat->code( ).
\end{SaveVerbatim}

\UseCoding{Foo}

\end{document}
```

If you want to be really systematic, it would also be possible to create a `SaveCoding` environment, although that's probably overkill.